# issue setting up app gateway ingress controller(agic) azure kubernetes service(aks)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-rbac

I have followed the steps from the following guide to set up an agic in azure:
https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/setup/install-existing.md

I have a vnet with an aks cluster(rbac enabled) in one subnet and an app gateway in another. I have followed the steps for authorizing ARM using service principal as well as aad pod identity.

However, in both cases, once the ingress controller has been installed using the helm-config.yaml file, the pod's logs show that it is running but not ready.

**The following are when using the aad pod identity to authenticate**

The events shown by `kubectl describe pod` are:
[events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5Wvb.png)

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  20m                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/ingress-azure-57bcc69687-bqbdn to aks-agentpool-29530272-vmss000002
  Normal   Pulling    20m                  kubelet            Pulling image "mcr.microsoft.com/azure-application-gateway/kubernetes-ingress:1.2.1"
  Normal   Pulled     20m                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "mcr.microsoft.com/azure-application-gateway/kubernetes-ingress:1.2.1"
  Normal   Created    20m                  kubelet            Created container ingress-azure
  Normal   Started    20m                  kubelet            Started container ingress-azure
  Warning  Unhealthy  41s (x117 over 20m)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.2.0.83:8123/health/ready: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

The logs shown by `kubectl logs -f` contain the following errors:
[logs error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D7JS.png)

```
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: I1015 07:29:04.152565       1 utils.go:115] Using verbosity level 3 from environment variable APPGW_VERBOSITY_LEVEL
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: I1015 07:29:04.152726       1 main.go:78] Unable to load cloud provider config '/etc/appgw/azure.json'. Error: Reading Az Context file
 "/etc/appgw/azure.json" failed: open /etc/appgw/azure.json: permission denied
E1015 07:29:04.172959       1 context.go:198] Error fetching AGIC Pod (This may happen if AGIC is running in a test environment). Error: pods "ingress-azure-57bcc69687-bqbdn" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot get resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
I1015 07:29:04.172990       1 environment.go:240] KUBERNETES_WATCHNAMESPACE is not set. Watching all available namespaces.
I1015 07:29:04.173096       1 main.go:128] Appication Gateway Details: Subscription="e14827fd-ae03-4832-9388-ef0aa3f28693" Resource Group="rg-test" Name="appGateway"
I1015 07:29:04.173107       1 auth.go:46] Creating authorizer from Azure Managed Service Identity
I1015 07:29:04.173365       1 httpserver.go:57] Starting API Server on :8123
I1015 07:33:07.865519       1 main.go:175] Ingress Controller will observe all namespaces.
I1015 07:33:07.894383       1 context.go:132] k8s context run started
I1015 07:33:07.894419       1 context.go:176] Waiting for initial cache sync
E1015 07:33:07.913698       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: ingresses.extensions is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "ingresses" in API group "extensions" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:07.914239       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:07.914307       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Secret: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:07.914613       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:07.915265       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: ingresses.extensions is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "ingresses" in API group "extensions" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:07.914752       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints:endpoints is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "endpoints" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:07.917430       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:07.919146       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Secret: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:07.919932       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:07.922582       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints:endpoints is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "endpoints" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:09.877700       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints:endpoints is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "endpoints" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:09.977016       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:09.994355       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Secret: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:10.030444       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: ingresses.extensions is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "ingresses" in API group "extensions" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:10.612903       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:13.730098       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints:endpoints is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "endpoints" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:14.333551       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:14.752686       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:15.022569       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Secret: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:15.992773       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: ingresses.extensions is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "ingresses" in API group "extensions" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:22.033914       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints:endpoints is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "endpoints" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:22.477987       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1015 07:33:25.552073       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20200326020446-6240434e1ad6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:ingress-azure" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

I have created the three role assignments as stated in the guide:

- AGIC's identity Contributor access to the App Gateway
- AGIC's identity Reader access to the App Gateway resource group
- Managed Identity Operator role to AGIC's identity for the cluster

Kindly help me in understanding the error.

Comment: You can find answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64317755/unable-to-load-cloud-provider-config-etc-appgw-azure-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I followed this [blogpost](https://jessicadeen.com/how-to-configure-azure-application-gateway-v2-on-an-existing-aks-cluster/) and was able to solve this. There were two things I changed from the guide I was following before:

- changed rbac enabled in helm-config.yaml to true
- used the following command to install ingress:

```
helm upgrade --install appgw-ingress-azure -f helm-config.yaml application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/ingress-azure
```

While the pod was ready and running after this, the events did show that it was unhealthy. so there is that. However, it solved the earlier issue

Comment: Hello did you ever solve this issue? Mine is display 404/502 but my pods seem fine.

Comment: No I didn't get a chance to look into this further

Comment: @James, try using ingress-azure Helm Chart v1.3.0 instead of v1.2.1.